# CSS nested divs & property inheritance

Tags: css

I've some CSS that sets up several classes that change the coloring inside of a div, called accents. The accent class changes the background-color of the div, the text color, and the link color. The issue is that when accent divs are nested inside of each other, the colors start to override each other, showing up incorrectly.

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/jlegosama/pen/OPRNoB?editors=110) (Using SASS) but the following is relevant code. Basically what is happening is when nesting one or more of these accents inside of each other, trying to define colors for elements inside of the wrappers, such as an anchor tag `<a>`, fails if the accent colors for the parent accent (`.accent-4`) are output after the styles for a child accent (`.accent-1`) because with the following markup, `.accent-4 a` also matches `.accent-4 .accent-1 a`.

**HTML**

```
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="accent-4">

    <h3>Gradparent</h3>
    <p>Text should be white and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>

    <section class="wrapper">
      <div class="accent-2">

        <h3>Parent</h3>
        <p>Text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>blue</a></p>
        <p>But the <a>links</a> are <a>white</a></p>

        <section class="wrapper">
          <div class="accent-1">

            <h3>Child</h3>
            <p>Text should be white and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>

          </div>
       </section>
     </div>
   </section>
 </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%; }

 .wrapper [class*="accent-"] {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block; }

  .wrapper [class*="accent-"] p, .wrapper [class*="accent-"] a, .wrapper [class*="accent-"] h3 { color: inherit; }

.accent-1 {
 background-color #333;
 color: white; }
 .accent-1 a { color: white; }

.accent-2 {
 background-color #ccc;
 color: black; }
 .accent-2 a { color: blue; }

.accent-3 {
 background-color salmon;
 color: black; }
 .accent-3 a { color: white; }

.accent-4 {
 background-color blue;
 color: white; }
 .accent-4 a { color: white; }

.accent-5 {
 background-color white;
 color: black;}
 .accent-5 a { color: blue; }
```

**How do I ensure that accents always have the correct colors and allow for infinite nesting?**

A few criteria:

- The colors for the accents may not always be what they are in the examples. This is actually part of a sass mixin that takes the accent colors as arguments. (Hence the color functions in the codepen).
- I say infinite nesting, but 3 levels is probably sufficient.
- I have already tried using the direct child selector (`.accent-1 > p a`). This is a simplified example and there will be additional complex elements inside the accents with other properties that will need to be different based off of what color the background of the accent is. Explicitly listing out each of these properties with the `>` selector for each of the 5 accents comes out to around 200KB of additional CSS
- Support for all modern browsers as well as back to IE8

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables):

```css
.accent-1, .accent-3, .accent-4 {
  --anchor-color: white;
}
.accent-2, .accent-5 {
  --anchor-color: #3488C9;
}
.accent-1 a, .accent-2 a, .accent-3 a, .accent-4 a, .accent-5 a {
  color: var(--anchor-color);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: #3488C9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

[class*="accent-"] {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
[class*="accent-"] p, [class*="accent-"] b, [class*="accent-"] strong, [class*="accent-"] i, [class*="accent-"] em, [class*="accent-"] blockquote,
[class*="accent-"] h1, [class*="accent-"] h2, [class*="accent-"] h3, [class*="accent-"] h4, [class*="accent-"] h5, [class*="accent-"] h6,
[class*="accent-"] ul, [class*="accent-"] ol, [class*="accent-"] li, [class*="accent-"] a {
  color: unset;
}

.accent-1 {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  --anchor-color: white;
}
.accent-2 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: black;
  --anchor-color: #3488C9;
}
.accent-3 {
  background-color: salmon;
  color: black;
  --anchor-color: white;
}
.accent-4 {
  background-color: #2A4D68;
  color: white;
  --anchor-color: white;
}
.accent-5 {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  --anchor-color: #3488C9;
}
.accent-1 a, .accent-2 a, .accent-3 a, .accent-4 a, .accent-5 a {
  color: var(--anchor-color);
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 25%;
}

[class*="correct"] {
  color: #fff !important;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.correct {
  background-color: green;
}

.incorrect {
  background-color: red;
}

em {
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="accent-1">
    <h3>Section A: Accent 1 <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong> </h3>
    <p>In this section, text should be white and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>
    <p><em>All the styles in this section are correct because the parent div has a class of .accent-1, which is output before the rest of the accent styles, allowing them to override the parent's styles</em></p>
    <section class="wrapper">
      <div class="accent-2">
        <h3>Section A: Accent 2 <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong> </h3>
        <p>In this section, text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>blue</a>.</p>
         <section class="wrapper">
           <div class="accent-3">
             <h3>Section A: Accent 3 <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong> </h3>
               <p>In this section, text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>
           </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="accent-4">
    <h3>Section B: Accent 4 <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong></h3>
   <p>In this section, text should be white and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>
    <section class="wrapper">
      <div class="accent-2">
        <h3>Section B: Accent 2 <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong></h3>
         <p>In this section, text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>blue</a>.</p>
         <p><em>This is incorrect because blue .accent-4 comes after light-grey .accent-2 in the stylesheet and the elements inside this section are also children of a blue .accent-4 section (SectionB:accent-4)</em></p>
         <section class="wrapper">
           <div class="accent-1">
             <h3>Section B: Accent 3 <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong></h3>
               <p>In this section, text should be white and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>
               <p><em>This is only correct because the colors for the blue parent section (SectionB:Accent4) are being applied and  are the same.</em></p>
           </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="accent-1">
    <h3>Section C: Accent 1 <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong> </h3>
    <p>In this section, text should be white and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>
    <p><em>All the styles in this section are correct because the parent div has a class of .accent-1, which is output before the rest of the accent styles, allowing them to override the parent's styles</em></p>
     <section class="wrapper col-4">
      <div class="accent-5">
        <h3>Section C: Accent 5</h3>
        <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong>
        <p>In this section, text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>blue</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="wrapper col-4">
      <div class="accent-2"> 
        <h3>Section C: Accent 2</h3>
        <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong>
        <p>In this section, text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>blue</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="wrapper col-4">
      <div class="accent-3"> 
        <h3>Section C: Accent 3</h3>
        <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong>
        <p>In this section, text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="wrapper col-4">
      <div class="accent-4"> 
        <h3>Section 3: Accent 4</h3>
        <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong>
        <p>In this section, text should be white and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="accent-4">
     <h3>Section D: Accent 4 <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong></h3>
     <p>In this section, text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>
     <section class="wrapper col-4">
      <div class="accent-5">
         <h3>Section D: Accent 5</h3>
        <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong>
        <p>In this section, text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>blue</a>.</p>
        <p><em>This is correct because the styles for .accent-5 are output after the styles for the parent div with .accent-4 class</em></p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="wrapper col-4">
      <div class="accent-3"> 
        <h3>Section D: Accent 3</h3>
        <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong>
        <p>In this section, text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="wrapper col-4">
      <div class="accent-2"> 
        <h3>Section D: Accent 2</h3>
        <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong>
        <p>In this section, text should be black and <a>links</a> should be <a>blue</a>.</p>
        <p><em>Once again, this is incorrect because the styles for the .accent-2 class are output before the styles for the .accent-4 class of the parent wrapper.</em></p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="wrapper col-4">
      <div class="accent-1"> 
        <h3>Section D: Accent 1</h3>
        <strong class="correct">CORRECT</strong>
        <p>In this section, text should be white and <a>links</a> should be <a>white</a>.</p>
        <p><em>And again, this is only correct because the foreground colors for .accent-4 happen to be the same as .accent-1</em></p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>
```

But note that currently there is small browser support.

Comment: Caniuse shows that browser support is limited to Firefox only. That's hardly a solution. http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20variables